# How to make a function if a number is greater than others

Tags: javascript, html

I have buttons so once you click them, it adds one to a number next to it.I want to compare these numbers and have a function happen based on which one is bigger. Here's my code

```
    <button class="song1box" onClick="onClick()"></button>
    <p id = "song1">Song #1</p>
    <button class="song2box" onClick="onClick2()"></button>
    <p id = "song2">Song #2</p>
    <button class="song3box" onClick="onClick3()"></button>
    <p id = "song3">Song #3</p>
    <button class="song4box" onClick="onClick4()"></button>
    <p id = "song4">Song #4</p>
    <button class="song5box" onClick="onClick5()"></button>
    <p id = "song5">Song #5</p>

    <p id="clickp1">Clicks: <a id="clicks1">0</a></p>
    <p id="clickp2">Clicks: <a id="clicks2">0</a></p>
    <p id="clickp3">Clicks: <a id="clicks3">0</a></p>
    <p id="clickp4">Clicks: <a id="clicks4">0</a></p>
    <p id="clickp5">Clicks: <a id="clicks5">0</a></p>

JAVASCRIPT:

    const click1var = document.getElementById("clicks1").value
    const click2var = document.getElementById("clicks2").value
    const click3var = document.getElementById("clicks3").value
    const click4var = document.getElementById("clicks4").value
    const click5var = document.getElementById("clicks5").value

    playbutton.onclick = function(){
    ad.play();
    if (Math.max(click1var, click2var, click3var, click4var, click5var) == click1var){
        song1.play();
    }
    if (Math.max(click1var, click2var, click3var, click4var, click5var) == click2var){
        song2.play();
    }
    if (Math.max(click1var, click2var, click3var, click4var, click5var) == click3var){
        song3.play();
    }
    if (Math.max(click1var, click2var, click3var, click4var, click5var) == click4var){
        song4.play();
    }
    if (Math.max(click1var, click2var, click3var, click4var, click5var) == click5var){
        song5.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem you have is that you are getting the values of the elements as soon as the page loads, but never again. So `click*var` is always going to be 0. Move that code into your `onclick` function. There's also no element with an id `playbutton` so `playbutton.onclick =` should be throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two variables, `clickAVar` and `clickBVar`. You can execute code based on which one is bigger using the following snippet.

```
if(clickAVar > clickBVar){
  // insert code here for when A is bigger
} else {
  // insert code here for when B is bigger (or they're equal)
}
```

I'll leave it up to you to integrate this into your app.